# Issues with circle task in Canvas

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, html5-canvas

I have been given the following task, but I am getting errors that can be seen when the code snippet is run. I would like some help figuring out what exactly I am doing wrong.

Basically, I need to draw a circle, make it so that it moves and changes the direction/color when touching the walls of the screen.

> Task: create a Circle class with the following properties:
>
> - x - the initial value of the coordinate x
> - y is the initial value of the y coordinate
> - radius - values ​​of width and height
> - color - fill color Describe the methods:
> - draw () - marks off on the screen an element that is described by the given properties
> - setColor (newColor) - Changes the fill color to newColor
> - move ({x = 0, y = 0}) - moves the captured object by the vector (x, y) - each time period (for example, 100 ms) changes (adds \ subtracts)
>   to the values ​​x and y, respectively. When a circle collides with any
>   edge of the screen it is necessary to realize its mirror reflection
>   (change the value of the corresponding coordinate of the vector on the
>   opposite of the value of the sign, and call this method with the new
>   vector) and generate the collision event, collision, which is captured
>   at the document level.Hang on this event a handler that will change
>   the color of the pouring of the circle into another (random) value.
>   Movement occurs until the stop method is called.
> - stop () - stops the circle movement
>
> If the Escape button on the keyboard was pressed, the movement should stop.

I created a canvas and set the frame to move. I drew a circle and tried to move it using setInterval(), but it seems like I'm losing the context.

```js
let c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");

let xinc = 1;
let yinc = 1;

class Circle {
  constructor(xpos, ypos, radius, color) {
    this.xpos = xpos;
    this.ypos = ypos;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
  }

  move(xpos, ypos) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    this.draw();

    xpos += xinc;
    ypos += yinc;
    console.log(xpos, ypos);
    if ((this.xpos > c.width - this.radius) || (this.xpos < 0 + this.radius)) {
      xinc = -xinc;
    }
    if ((this.ypos > c.height - this.radius) || (this.ypos < 0 + this.radius)) {
      yinc = -yinc;
    }
    setInterval(this.move, 10);
    //this.draw();
  }

}

let circle = new Circle(200, 300, 50, "red");
circle.draw();
circle.move(200, 300);
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1335" height="650" style="border: 1px solid"> </canvas>
```

I am just starting to learn events and DOMs, please help me correctly implement this task

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `this.move` to `setInterval` with no context - just a function, with no `this` to call it in. You can pass in `this.move.bind(this)` to create a *bound* function. You can also do it once in the constructor: `this.move = this.move.bind(this)`.

Also, the call to `beginPath` in `move` seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, I have rewritten so setInterval (this.move (xpos, ypos) .bind (this), 10); and now through console.log (xpos, ypos) I see that the coordinates are changing. However, the draw () method does not work, and the circle is not redrawn

Comment: Uh, not `this.move(xpos, ypos).bind(this)`, but just `this.move.bind(this)`. However, you never update `this.xpos` and only modify local variables.